# Extensive memtest

Tags: memory

On Ubuntu 10.04 (Kernel: 2.6.28), I installed new memory and ran memtest for 13 hours. When I rebooted the machine, I got an IOH overheat error and the machine did not boot. I waited for 5 mins, then started the machine again. It booted into the OS and everything seems to be fine. Is there any way to test if there is any damage to the IOH because of overheating?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you could test directly (damage from overheating will either be catastrophic or intermittent, much like problems that occur while the system is overheated --- either it will crash or it will behave "strangely").

The fact that your system overheated as a result of running memtest though makes me think you have a bigger problem (inadequate cooling) -- I'd report the problem to the manufacturer, and consider replacing the system.